# Can a pandas DataFrame hold non-scalar values?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I'd like a DataFrame to store non-primitive types, in particular I would need a column that can have lists as its items.

```
pd.DataFrame( [["foo","bar"],["rab","oof"]], ["my-column-of-lists"] )
```

should result in a DataFrame with one column (`my-column-of-lists`) and 2 rows (`["foo","bar"]` and `["rab","oof"]`).

Is that possible?

Comment: Strictly, yes. But you need to get clever these days because of all the type-checking pandas does to avoid upsetting the rest of the 99% of the users with weird results (like lists in cells). I have even managed to have entire DataFrames within cells of a DataFrame (but I don't recommend doing that, performance was in the toilet and indexing was a cobweb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my-column-of-lists': [["foo","bar"],["rab","oof"]]})
print (df)
  my-column-of-lists
0         [foo, bar]
1         [rab, oof]
```

Or pass `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([["foo","bar"],["rab","oof"]], name='my-column-of-lists'))
print (df)
  my-column-of-lists
0         [foo, bar]
1         [rab, oof]
```